# How disable local pickup, when cart weight = 0 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

pls how can I disable local pickup depending on a cart total weight? I want to disable possibility for local pickup when the cart total weight == 0. I used this snippet found elsewhere and modified, but it is not working and the local pickup is still offered

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping', 9999, 2 );
    
function bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping( $rates, $package ) {
     
     if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() == 0 ) {
       
          unset( $rates['local_pickup'] );
          unset( $rates['local_delivery'] );
     
     } 
     return $rates;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong please?

---

Actually my code mentioned above is working. I did not realized two things:

1. ID of my local_pickup was wrong, I did not explore the page to find out, that the correct variable name is 'local_pickup:13' (code updated)
2. To see changes on the web I always have to open the site in anonymous window. Even Ctrl+F5, Ctrl+Shift+R in Chrome does not help.

Comment: You should not change your question code, once people have already answered your question… Instead you can add an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can count total weight by WC()->cart->cart_contents loop.
try this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_based_on_weight', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_based_on_weight( $rates, $package ) {
    
    $cart_total_weight = 0;
 
    $shipping_id = 'local_pickup'; // your shipping id
 
    // Calculate cart weight total.
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $value ){
        $cart_total_weight += $value['data']->weight * $value['quantity'];
    }
    
    // check cart total
    if( $cart_total_weight <= 0 ){
        unset( $rates[ $shipping_id ] );
    }
 
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Actually my code mentioned above is working. I did not realized two things:


1. ID of my local_pickup was wrong, I did not explore the page to find out, that the correct variable name is 'local_pickup:13' (code updated)


2. To see changes on the web I always have to open the site in anonymous window. Even Ctrl+F5, Ctrl+Shift+R in Chrome does not help.